# value of loop variable in FileReader onloadend

Tags: javascript, filereader

i am trying to process a list of files which was created via html5 dropzone/fileinput. files[] is actually not a FileList but an array containing File objects.

This works as long as files[] contains only 1-2 files, but with more files suddenly each console output is the same (last file in files[]). For example with 4 files i get 4 times "filereader.onloaded: File: save-view.html index:4" with save-view.html being the last file.

```
    for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        var filereader = new FileReader();
        filereader.myfile = files[i];
        filereader.myindex = i;

        filereader.onloadend = function()
        {
            console.log("filereader.onloaded: File: "+filereader.myfile.name+" index:" +filereader.myindex);
            //here we call some other functions which most likely don't cause any problems
        }
        filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```

I have tried a lot like creating a filereader array (so that var filereader is never overwritten) and saving the index as an additional member variable of filereader (so that the value would not be lost after i++), but none of that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filereader` changes with each iteration of the loop and the loop is not going to wait for the callback to fire before it continues each time. So whenever the onload callback triggers, `filereader` probably doesn't have the FileReader object associated with the specific onload event.

To ensure that you use the correct FileReader object in the callback use the `this` keyword, or you can get it from the event object passed to the callback;

```
filereader.onloadend = function(event)
{
    console.log("filereader.onloaded: File: "+this.myfile.name+" index:" +event.target.myindex);
    //here we call some other functions which most likely don't cause any problems
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need proper closure. In Javascript the scope of variables doesn't depend on the curly braces, but on which function they're in. So even when your variable is defined within the for-loop, it is actually also available outside of it, and it is the only one and same variable during the whole loop.

You can solve this by adding a proper closure:

```
for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    (function(f, i)
    {
        var filereader = new FileReader();
        filereader.onloadend = function()
        {
            console.log("filereader.onloaded: File: "+f.name+" index:" +i);
            //here we call some other functions which most likely don't cause any problems
        }
        filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    })(files[i], i);
}
```

Note that the `i` defined in the for-loop is now a different variable than the `i` defined in the anonymous function argument list. By passing the variables through a function, they are copied to new variables which will remain independent throughout the script. Also, a new `filereader` variable is now created for each iteration of the for-loop.